# How do I copy a 2 Dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, copy

I need to make a copy of a fairly large 2 dimensional array for a project I am working on. I have two 2D arrays:

```
int[][]current;
int[][]old;
```

I also have two methods to do the copying. I need to copy the array because current is regularly being updated.

```
public void old(){
  old=current
}
```

and

```
public void keepold(){
  current=old
}
```

However, this does not work. If I were to call old, make an update on current, and then call keepold, current is not equal to what it was originally. Why would this be?

Thanks

Comment: When you find yourself needing to copy multi-dimensional arrays, you may find it's time to consider creating a new class to better manage this data.

Comment: Do you know how to copy a one dimensional array in Java?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/
One can declare a question as  a homework question. But tags are for classification and "homework" is not a good classifier, IMO

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`current=old` or `old=current` makes the two array refer to the same thing, so if you subsequently modify `current`, `old` will be modified too. To copy the content of an array to another array, use the for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<old.length; i++)
  for(int j=0; j<old[i].length; j++)
    old[i][j]=current[i][j];
```

PS: For a one-dimensional array, you can avoid creating your own for loop by using [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

Comment: Thanks! Will Arrays.deepEquals(current, old) work equally as well?

Comment: no. what Arrays.deepEquals is comparing two array and return true if their contents are identical.
Arrays.copyOf works equally for a _one-dimensional_ array

Comment: Shouldn't you be assigning old to current and not the other way round

Answer (score 74):

Since Java 8, using the streams API:

```
int[][] copy = Arrays.stream(matrix).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: Thats nice. Really nice.

Comment: Is it faster than the other answers here?

Comment: Probably, the streaming API is highly optimized and the initialization in the toArray-method as well. Presizing arrays is rarely a good choice.

Comment: IntelliJ had a bit to say about method references. A lovely solution!
`Arrays.stream(grid).map(int[]::clone).toArray(int[][]::new);`

Comment: why here we don't need to specify the array size for example, int[3][3]::new??

Comment: Because you pass a method reference to the constructor of a two-dimensional int array `int[][]::new` to the `toArray` collector. The collector will call the provided method reference, i.e. the constructor with appropriate dimension arguments for you.

Answer (score 26):

> ```
> /**
>  * Clones the provided array
>  * 
>  * @param src
>  * @return a new clone of the provided array
>  */
> public static int[][] cloneArray(int[][] src) {
>     int length = src.length;
>     int[][] target = new int[length][src[0].length];
>     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
>         System.arraycopy(src[i], 0, target[i], 0, src[i].length);
>     }
>     return target;
> }
> ```

Is it possible to modify this code to support **n-dimensional arrays of Objects**?

You would need to support arbitrary lengths of arrays and check if the src and destination have the same dimensions, <s>and you would also need to copy each element of each array *recursively*, in case the Object was also an array.</s>

It's been a while since I posted this, but I found a **[nice example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770926/java-n-dimensional-arrays)** of one way to create an n-dimensional array class. The class takes zero or more integers in the constructor, specifying the respective size of each dimension. The class uses an underlying *flat* array `Object[]` and calculates the index of each element using the dimensions and an array of multipliers. (This is how arrays are done in the C programming language.)

Copying an instance of `NDimensionalArray` would be as easy as copying any other 2D array, though you need to assert that each `NDimensionalArray` object has equal dimensions. This is probably the easiest way to do it, since there is no recursion, and this makes representation and access much simpler.

Answer (score 12):

I solved it writing a simple function to copy multidimensional int arrays using System.arraycopy

```
public static void arrayCopy(int[][] aSource, int[][] aDestination) {
    for (int i = 0; i < aSource.length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(aSource[i], 0, aDestination[i], 0, aSource[i].length);
    }
}
```

or actually I improved it for for my use case:

```
/**
 * Clones the provided array
 * 
 * @param src
 * @return a new clone of the provided array
 */
public static int[][] cloneArray(int[][] src) {
    int length = src.length;
    int[][] target = new int[length][src[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(src[i], 0, target[i], 0, src[i].length);
    }
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do as follows:

```
public static int[][] copy(int[][] src) {
    int[][] dst = new int[src.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
        dst[i] = Arrays.copyOf(src[i], src[i].length);
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using java 8 this can be done with

```
int[][] destination=Arrays.stream(source)
                    .map(a ->  Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length))
                    .toArray(int[][]::new);
```

Comment: why here we don't need to specify the array size  for example, int[3][3]::new?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in java are objects, and all objects are [passed by reference](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html). In order to really "copy" an array, instead of creating another name for an array, you have to go and create a new array and copy over all the values. Note that System.arrayCopy will copy 1-dimensional arrays fully, but NOT 2-dimensional arrays. The reason is that a 2D array is in fact a 1D array of 1D arrays, and arrayCopy copies over pointers to the same internal 1D arrays.

Comment: Arrays are not objects.  Array variables are references, similar to how object variables are references, but they are not objects.

Comment: Arrays are objects.  Java Language Specification Chapter 10.. *In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.* https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#:~:text=In%20the%20Java%20programming%20language,be%20invoked%20on%20an%20array.

Answer (score 0):

```
current = old ;
```

Assignment operations doesnot copy elements of one array to another. You are just making the `current` matrix refer to the `old` matrix. You need to do a member wise copy.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function:

```
public static int[][] copy(final int[][] array) {
    if (array != null) {
        final int[][] copy = new int[array.length][];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            final int[] row = array[i];

            copy[i] = new int[row.length];
            System.arraycopy(row, 0, copy[i], 0, row.length);
        }

        return copy;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The big advantage of this approach is that it can also copy arrays that don't have the same row count such as:

```
final int[][] array = new int[][] { { 5, 3, 6 }, { 1 } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it by using loops.

```
public static int[][] makeCopy(int[][] array){
    b=new int[array.length][];

    for(int row=0; row<array.length; ++row){
        b[row]=new int[array[row].length];
        for(int col=0; col<b[row].length; ++col){
            b[row][col]=array[row][col];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Take care, this is dimensions slower than solutions based on System.arraycopy. System.arraycopy is implemented natively based on the underlying hardware platform.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use a for each loop

```
int r=0;
for(int[] array:old){
    int c=0;
    for(int element:array)
        current[r][c++]=array;
    r++;
}
```

Or

```
int c=0;
for(int array[]:old){
    System.arraycopy(array,0,current[c++],0,array.length);
}
```

However something like:

```
int c=0;
for(int[] array:old){
    current[c++]=array;
}
```

would be wrong as it would just copy references of the subarrays of old and changes made to old would be reflected in current.

Answer (score -2):

```
public  static byte[][] arrayCopy(byte[][] arr){
    if(arr!=null){
        int[][] arrCopy = new int[arr.length][] ;
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arrCopy, 0, arr.length);
        return arrCopy;
    }else { return new int[][]{};}
}
```

Answer (score -8):

You can give below code a try,

```
public void multiArrayCopy(int[][] source,int[][] destination){
destination=source.clone();}
```

Hope it works.

Comment: No, this won't work. Because assigning to the local variable `destination` has no effect after `multiArrayCopy` at all.