# Loading all values of 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm attempting to create a 2d puzzle slider game. I created my own object called gamestate to store the parent gamestate and the new gamestate, as I plan on solving it using BFS. A sample array will look like

```
int[][] tArr = {{1,5,2},{3,4,0},{6,8,7}};
```

Which implies

[1, 5, 2,
3, 4, 0,
6, 8, 7]

To store this state I used the following for loop, which brings **`indexOutOfBounds exceptions`**.

```
public class GameState {
public int[][] state; //state of the puzzle
public GameState parent; //parent in the game tree

public GameState() {
    //initialize state to zeros, parent to null
    state = new int[0][0];
    parent = null;
}

public GameState(int[][] state) {
    //initialize this.state to state, parent to null
    this.state = state;

    parent = null;
}

public GameState(int[][] state, GameState parent) {
    //initialize this.state to state, this.parent to parent
    this.state = new int[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            this.state[i][j] = state[i][j];
        }
    }

    this.parent = parent;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: In the 3rd constructor you're initializing `state` with `new int[0][0]`. You cannot then access any element of the array.

Comment: As a side note it is not `[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 7]`, but `[[1, 5, 2], [3, 4, 0], [6, 8, 7]]`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52608790/5640649)

Answer (score 2):

- For the `GameState()` constructor (default constructor):

Change this `state = new int[0][0];` to this: `state = new int[`**`3`**`][`**`3`**`];`. This way you initialize the array with capacity for (3)x(3) elements.

- For the `GameState(int[][] state, GameState parent)` constructor:

Change this `this.state = new int[0][0];` to `this.state = new int[`**`state.length`**][**`state.length > 0 ? state[0].length : 0`**`];`

This way, you initialize the array with capacity for

(`state.length`)x(`state[0].length` or `0` if `state.length` is `0`) elements.

Also, you must for loop until `state.length` with `i` and until `state[i].length` with `j`.

In `GameState` constructor, like this:

```
public GameState(int[][] state, GameState parent) {
    //initialize this.state to state, this.parent to parent
    this.state = new int[state.length][state.length > 0 ? state[0].length : 0];
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < state[i].length; j++) {
            this.state[i][j] = state[i][j];
        }
    }

    this.parent = parent;
}
```

---

Also, as a side note it is not `[1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 8, 7]`,

but `[[1, 5, 2], [3, 4, 0], [6, 8, 7]]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the initialisation part.

```
this.state = new int[0][0];
```

This code will create a **zero sized** two dimentional aray. That's why you get indexOutOfBounds exceptions when you try to set values in it.

If you want to initialize your array with zeros, the correct syntax is :

```
this.state = {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};
```

see the official documentation for full reference : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: I think `this.state = state = new int[3][3];` is a clearer code (which does the same as `this.state = {{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};`). But yours is fine too. However take into account that the `indexOutOfBounds ` is not happening in that constructor `GameState()` but in this one: `GameState(int[][] state, GameState parent)` which you do not mention in your answer.

Comment: You're right, `new int[3][3];` would have the same effect (because the default value of the primitive type "int" is 0). I chose to post the "explicit" version because I thought it would be more pedagogic.

Comment: I did not mention any constructor method. Of course, he will have to correct both.

Answer (score 0):

In the 3rd constructor you're initializing `this.state` with an empty array. It has no elements and thus a length of `0`. Using a for loop to access any element of this array rises an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Since you're passing in a `state` as parameter, you probably want to copy it's values to the field `state`.

You can do this like that:

```
public GameState(int[][] state, GameState parent) {
    this.state = new int[state.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        if (state[i] != null) {
            this.state[i] = Arrays.copyOf(state[i], state[i].length);
        }
    }

    this.parent = parent;
}
```

You could of course call `Arrays.of(state)` but this wouldn't return a deep copy of `state`. For every `i` you would have `this.state[i] == state[i]`.

---

Further reading: [How do I copy a 2 Dimensional array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617016/how-do-i-copy-a-2-dimensional-array-in-java)