# Assigning the same object after changes, modifies the first assignment

Tags: java

I have an algorithm to generate a solved Sudoku board. In my tests I want to check whether two subsequent calls to the `fillBoard()` method, generate a different board, with this code:

```
SudokuBoard sb = new SudokuBoard();
sb.fillBoard();
int [][] board1 = sb.getBoard();
sb.fillBoard();
int [][] board2 = sb.getBoard();
int same = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
        if(board1[i][y] == board2[i][y])
            same++;
    }
}
assertTrue(same < 10);
```

When I assign `sb.getBoard()` to `board2`, `board1` changes as well. How can that be solved?

Comment: [How do I copy a 2 Dimensional array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617016/how-do-i-copy-a-2-dimensional-array-in-java)

Comment: You either need to clone / copy the return value of `getBoard()` (or change `getBoard()` to return a copy), change `SudokuBoard` to use a new array for each `fillBoard()` call, or create a new `SudokuBoard`.