# I am not getting any output with this java code. When I run the code without calling methods, that is all the code is in the main method, it works

Tags: java, arrays, methods

'This declares matrixA, randomNumber, and size'

```
static int size;
static int matrixA [][] = new int [size][size];
static Random randomNumber = new Random();
```

'This method asks the user to enter an int. The input is used to set the size of an array'

```
static void setSize() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size");
    size = input.nextInt();
}
```

'This method fills the array with random numbers and prints the array. This is producing no output.'

```
static void fillMatrixA() {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixA[i].length; j++) {
        matrixA[i][j] = randomNumber.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println(matrixA[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

'When I call this method in the main method there is no output. The program has only one class. What could the problem be?'

Comment: Why do you have quote marks or ticks around your sentences of prose?

Comment: Sorry if this isn't the correct format. I'm new to stack overflow and I was having issues properly formatting my question/code to post. Is this not the right convention? I'm open for suggestions and I will edit my post.

Comment: Prose should be plain text, no need for any markup. Code should be either indented on all lines by four SPACE characters, or wrapped in a pair of triple back-ticks. Quotes start with an angle bracket, `>`. You can remove those quote or tick marks around your prose.

Answer (score 0):

When things seem screwy, (a) check your assumptions, (b) engage a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger).

Your assumption that `matrixA` has a length greater than zero is incorrect. A debugger would show the length to be zero.

When you initialize a `static` variable within the declaration statement, that code executes when the class is loaded. So `new int [size] [size]` executed very early, before your other code. When that line executed, it used the current value of `size`, which was zero. Why zero? Because that is the default value assigned to a primitive `int`.

Later, in your `setSize` method, you change the value of `size` from zero to the value input by the user. But that has no effect on your two-dimensional array. That array was initialized to a length of zero long before the `setSize` method executed.

See your [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/YcfKUK). You can fork that code, and play with it.

The problem you experienced is one reason why I like to do all my initializing within a constructor. I rarely use initialization with declaration syntax. But other reasonable programmers may differ on this point.

---

By the way, your code has much room for improvement.

First and foremost, you are likely overusing `static`. Anything marked `static` is not object-oriented. If you are writing much non-object-oriented code in Java, you are missing out on much of the value of Java. As a beginning student of Java, you should generally avoid using `static` in general. Even in real work, use `static` as a last-resort generally.

Another tip:

- Separate user-interface code from business logic code.
- Use local state generally. Avoid global variables. Pass needed info as arguments.
- Close your resources such as `Scanner` when done using them. Use try-with-resources syntax to do so more easily and briefly.
- Consider using a `static` factory method rather than a `public` constructor.

Taking that all into account, write a class to represent our *problem domain*, the business matter of managing a matrix whose height and width are of equal dimensions.

```java
package work.basil.example.squarematrix;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class SquareMatrix
{
    private int matrix[][];

    private SquareMatrix ( final int size )
    {
        // … Add code here validate passed argument.
        this.matrix = new int[ size ][ size ];
        this.randomize();
    }

    public static SquareMatrix ofSize ( final int size )
    {
        return new SquareMatrix( size );
    }

    public void randomize ( )
    {
        for ( int[] row : matrix )
        {
            for ( int columnIndex = 0 ; columnIndex < row.length ; columnIndex++ )
            {
                row[ columnIndex ] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , 10 );  // ( inclusive , exclusive )
            }
        }
    }

    public int[][] toArray ( )
    {
        // Code taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53397359/642706
        int[][] copy = Arrays.stream( this.matrix ).map( int[] :: clone ).toArray( int[][] :: new );
        return copy;
    }

    public CharSequence report ( )
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for ( int[] row : this.matrix )
        {
            sb.append( Arrays.toString( row ) );
            sb.append( "\n" );  // Using Unix convention of LINE FEED as a delimiter. https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm
        }
        return sb ;
    }
}
```

Notice how this class has a specific purpose: manage the content of our matrix. It is *not* responsible for interacting with a user. It is *not* responsible for running our larger app.

Also notice how the two-dimensional array is contained, and marked `private`. This is known as [*encapsulation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) in OOP. By encapsulating, we are free to internally use a two-dimensional array today, while leaving the door open to using some other data structure tomorrow. Other code calling upon our `SquareMatrix` class does not know or care anything about its internals.

And notice how the `toArray` method makes a copy of our internally-managed two-dimensional array. We do not want to provide direct access to our internal array, for a couple reasons. One reason is that direct access would break the encapsulation discussed above. Another reason is that we cannot trust the calling programmer; he/she may alter the content.

Next we create an "app" class, to provide a user-experience for accessing the bounty that is our square matrix.

```java
package work.basil.example.squarematrix;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SquareMatrixApp
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        SquareMatrixApp app = new SquareMatrixApp();

        int size = app.askUserForSize();
        SquareMatrix squareMatrix = SquareMatrix.ofSize( size );

        CharSequence report = squareMatrix.report();
        System.out.println( "report = \n" + report );

        int[][] array = squareMatrix.toArray();
        System.out.println( "array.length: " + array.length );
    }

    private int askUserForSize ( )
    {
        try (
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ) ;
        )
        {
            System.out.println( "Enter size: " );
            int size = scanner.nextInt();
            // … Add code here to validate inputs. For example, no negative numbers allowed.
            return size;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice here how the code for interacting with the user to gather input is segregated to its own method. That user-interface code does not know about, nor does it care about, matrices.

When run.

```
Enter size: 
3
report = 
[9, 3, 7]
[0, 7, 2]
[0, 7, 7]

array.length: 3
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I’m not at my computer now to try another solution. But I guess I will need to return size in setSize, declare matrixA in fillMatrixA and pass in size, and return MatrixA as I need it to perform other actions.