# Are 3D arrays better than other types of arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and I saw a video about 2D arrays online. But what about 3D arrays?

Is it possible to make a 3D array in Java? If so, how can this be done. Also, would using 3 separate 1D arrays (that are linked together) be equivalent to using 1 3D array? Finally, what is the efficiency of traversing through a 3D array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java N-Dimensional Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770926/java-n-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: No, three 1D arrays are not the same as one 3D array.

Comment: A 3D array of primitive integers: `int[][][] array;`  Whether you should be using a single 3D array, 3 x 1D arrays, or possible another data structure totally depends on the type of problem you are solving.

Comment: Have no idea why OP would think 3 1D array is equivalent to 1 3D array.  Just use an example, a 3D array, of 10-element in each dimension, gives you totally 10x10x10 = 1000 elements.  3 1D 10-element array gives you 30 elements.  Obviously different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a 3D array is quite possible in Java.  It's as simple as declaring the type `T[][][] array;`.  Three separate 1D arrays are not equivalent to one 3D array.  You would need `n` 2D arrays to be equivalent to one 3D array.  The efficiency of traversing a 3D array is practically O(n³).

Comment: So, for those who were sleeping through algebra/trig/whatever, is `O(n³)` a good thing?  And as Tim mentioned in a comment, wouldn't what you are trying to do affect the design?

Comment: Well O(n³) means the time it takes to traverse an n×n×n 3D array is proportional to n³.  So for instance, traversing a 1×1×1 3D array would require 1 iteration, whereas traversing a 2×2×2 array would require 8 iterations.  But as Tim mentioned, depending on what you're doing, a 3D array may not be the best data structure for solving your problem.