# How to work with arrays with an unknown number of dimensions in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, multidimensional-array, types

Is there some kind of datatype that supportes an n-dimensional array?
The problem is that when an array is created the number of dimensions a fixed from the beginning in the datatype:

```
T[] oneDimensional = ...
T[][] twoDimensional = ...
T[][][] threeDimensional = ...
...
T[]???[] nDimensional = ...
```

I can create this nDimensinal arrays as shown in the following code, but it seems that there is no way to save them in a variable except as an Object. But with an Object I can't work with the array.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> ??? createMultidimensionalArray(Class<T> clazz, int dimensions, int dimensionLength) {
    int[] dimArr = new int[dimensions];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
        dimArr[i] = dimensionLength;
    }
    ??? targetArray = (???) Array.newInstance(clazz, dimArr);
}
```

The question is: What datatype could fit the `???`?

---

Another attempt of me would be to create a class with some kind of linked array where every dimension gets it's own linked instance of that class. This idea is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770943/13148560). Still, since this idea would no longer use native arrays I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: Not sure if this post might help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770926/java-n-dimensional-arrays

Comment: @RhettHarrison & Federuco klez Culloca Not realy. These posts are about creating n-dimensional arrays. I would rather like to know how to store them. The accepted answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770943/13148560) of this post shows the way I'd like to avoid as explained above.

Comment: Then you'll need to explain why you want to keep using native arrays in the first place. And even then I can't think of a good way to do this with native arrays.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Simply accessebility and dependency of the rest of the program. Otherwise I could just put an endless amount of lists inside each other. I can't think of a good way to do this whith arrays eigher. Thats why I asked this question in the first place.

Comment: There isn't a better way.  Sorry.  Java doesn't have a syntax or data types for handling arrays with an indefinite number of dimensions.  (And I can't think of any PL that does ...)

Comment: *"The question is: What datatype could fit the ????"* - The only Java types that would (slightly) work here are `Object` or `Object[]`, I think.  And you know where that will lead ...